# CustomTabs shows ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME after 302 Redirect

Tags: android, deep-linking, chrome-custom-tabs, uri-scheme

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 login flow using Custom Tabs, but after login has been successful a 302 Redirect is retrieved with url as the following: "my.app:/oauth2/code?xxx".

Now I have declared redirect URI in AndroidManifest to listen to this, but ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME is seen :/

```
<intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="oauth2"
                android:scheme="my.app"
                android:pathPrefix="/code"
            />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I've tried different url-schemes to listen to, but none seems to be triggered to open my app.

Comment: Shouldn't the proper redirect URL be `my.app://oauth2/code?xxx`

Comment: Do you really have a dot in your scheme?

Comment: Yes, but that does not interfere when defining an scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with the identification happening in another app. So when I resumed the CustomTabs, somehow the context was lost. :/

**Basically this is what we wanted to do:**

*MyApp -> CustomTabs -> Identify with other app (from redirect) -> Resume CustomTabs (loading screen) -> redirect to MyApp.*

But since the second redirect couldn't be made, we tried another angle for the problem.

**Our solution that worked was to break up the flow for the authentication:**

*MyApp -> CustomTabs -> redirect to MyApp -> Identify with another app -> redirect to MyApp -> CustomTabs (loading screen) -> redirect to MyApp with result.*

Hopefully this helps someone with similar issue at least.